# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '('

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to use this cypher query

```
MATCH (n:PRODUCT_LOT_1)<-[:SHIPS|CONTAINS*..]-(s:SHIPMENT_1)  
WHERE  n.lot_id IN ['17'] AND 
EXISTS { MATCH (n)<-[:STORES|:HAS|:CONTAINS*..]-(loc:STORAGE_AREA_1) 
         WHERE loc.uuid IN ['d3177e9c-ddd0-48f7-8ad8-2209d64383d0','4f3fc27d-92f9-48e0-8446-6d3c2dd7b471']} 
RETURN n.lot_quantity;
```

but it giving syntax error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, ':', ',' or '}' (line 1, column 108 (offset: 107))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is syntactically wrong, in this statement you used
`MATCH (n)<-[:STORES|:HAS|:CONTAINS*..]-(loc:STORAGE_AREA_1)`, colon before each relationship type, which is not required try this instead:

```
MATCH (n:PRODUCT_LOT_1)<-[:SHIPS|CONTAINS*..]-(s:SHIPMENT_1)  
WHERE  n.lot_id IN ['17'] AND 
EXISTS { MATCH (n)<-[:STORES|HAS|CONTAINS*..]-(loc:STORAGE_AREA_1) 
         WHERE loc.uuid IN ['d3177e9c-ddd0-48f7-8ad8-2209d64383d0','4f3fc27d-92f9-48e0-8446-6d3c2dd7b471']} 
RETURN n.lot_quantity;
```

Comment: the EXISTS + MATCH syntax is correct. It is introduced in version 4. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/where/